# Laravel 5 dynamic input fields saving relation to database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dynamic input field called `name="step[]"`. When submitting the form and displaying the `$request->step` using dd, I get this:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "Test Step 1"
  1 => "Test Step 2"
  2 => "Test Step 3"
]
```

So it is an array. Now, when I want to insert the data using:

```
    $project = new Project;

    $project->name = $request->name;

    $project->save();

    $project->steps()->saveMany($request->step);
```

I am getting this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given
```

Project Model:

```
public function steps()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Step');
}
```

My goal is to create a new `Project` and save it to the database, and save all `steps` in my `Step` table. So each Project hasMany steps. Not sure why I am getting the above error though, since I am passing an array?

Comment: An `array` yes. An `array` of models, no. `$project->steps()->saveMany( /** array of models expected */)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually realize using a foreach loop. Your relation method seems to look OK. Does this work?

```
foreach($request->steps as $step) {
  $project->steps()->create(['step' => $step]);
}
```

Comment: This works in the meanwhile :) I wanted to do something without using a foreach, but since David Barker pointed out to me why I am getting the error, I can work on achieving what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the attach method?

```
$project->steps()->attach($resquest->input('steps'));
```